# Adding optional filter in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a multi valued parameter in my ssrs report. (Bus numbers) the question is how can I make the data set filter property optional? i've seen a blog that makes the filtering optional but my question is how can i do that if my parameter is multi valued?

http://www.andrewshough.com/development/sqlserver/ssrs/optional-filter-in-ssrs/

I tried adding a "No Filter" in my selection list but i cant seem to make it work.

```
=IIF(Parameters!BusNumber.Value = "No Filter", "",Fields!BusNumber.Value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically, if you have a *multi-valued* parameter, there's an implicit way to "not filter": **select all options**.

As a user, if I get to choose a "filter" parameter `@OnlyTheseCategoryIds`, and I check the `Select all` option, I'd expect my results to come through "unfiltered" (even though technically it is filtered, just every row passes that filter).

You've already mentioned one more explicit alternative ("No Filter" option), but "cant seem to make it work" is hardly enough info for us to be able to help you (other than completely spelling out how to do it).

Another alternative would be to create a [cascading parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337498%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) *before* the filter-one, something like `@FilterOnCategories` (boolean). Only if "True" is selected will the second parameter be available.

Comment: +1; in cases like this it's useful to set the Default Values the same as the Available Values; this way all are selected by default and the user doesn't need to take any action. Implicitly not filtering, as you accurately describe.